# Shared preferences button switch

Tags: android, sharedpreferences

I am trying switch buttons using shared preferences, so that when I open my app, the appropriate button will be displayed. 
This is my code for setting and getting shared preferences:

```
private void setRequestUpdatesButtonState(boolean state) {
    PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this)
            .edit()
            .putBoolean(Constants.PREF_IS_BUTTON_PRESSED, state)
            .apply();
}

private boolean getRequestUpdatesButtonState() {
    return PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this)
            .getBoolean(Constants.PREF_IS_BUTTON_PRESSED, false);
}
```

then inside onCreate method I check for the shared preferences to display the appropriate button:

```
if(getRequestUpdatesButtonState()) {
        mRequestRemoveUpdates.setCircleRadius(34);
        mRequestRemoveUpdates.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_cancel);
    }
    else {
        mRequestRemoveUpdates.setCircleRadius(34);
        mRequestRemoveUpdates.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_start);
    }
```

Also inside the onClick method, when the button is clicked, I change shared preferences depending on the situation, along with the button image itself:

```
if(getRequestUpdatesButtonState()) {
      boolean updatesRequested = true;
      setRequestUpdatesButtonState(updatesRequested);
      mRequestRemoveUpdates.setCircleRadius(34);
                     mRequestRemoveUpdates.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_cancel);
            }
else {
     boolean updatesRequested = false;
     setRequestUpdatesButtonState(updatesRequested);
     mRequestRemoveUpdates.setCircleRadius(34);
                mRequestRemoveUpdates.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_start);
}
```

But it does not work.
Obviously, I need to get rid of the code duplications, but I am trying to make it function properly at first, which I am struggling to achieve; and after that I would clean it up.

Comment: Seems like a logic issue. You want your switch to toggle but you somehow didn't really "toggle" it in your `onClick` method. Reverse your logic inside onClick's if..else.. statement and try.

Comment: I'm using CircledImageView as a button, inside my getRequestUpdatesButtonState I use false as default value, then inside onClick I change shared preferences from false to true, and vice versa, also I change the button image:                                                                      either mRequestRemoveUpdates.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_cancel);     Or         mRequestRemoveUpdates.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_start); changing the button image is used as a toggle

Comment: Doesn't matter what default value you used. In your `onClick` method, you read the value from `SharedPreferences` with `getRequestUpdatesButtonState()`. It tells you your current state is `true` (or false) and you are still trying to update it with the same state. To put it simply, you are not toggling it.

Comment: ok, then would it be correct to use something like this: boolean something = !getRequestUpdatesButtonState() and then put that value in: setRequestUpdatesButtonState(something) , would it then add the opposite boolean value, or am I still getting it wrong?

Comment: Just try it out and you will know. Remember to reverse your `View` logic as well to get a proper visual feedback.

Comment: seem to work now, thank you, really appreciate it. About reversing view logic, my approach is a bit primitive I suppose, since I just change the button image. Do you suggest to use a separate method like update UI and then just call it inside my onClick, or maybe something different?

Comment: That would be good since you have the same UI code in `onCreate()`, a separate method helps to centralize it and made it easier for modifications in the future. That's just my two cents, anyway.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what is your exact implementation but I have implemented similar function as you want.This code is for Login form, the layout consist of two `EditText` for username and password, a remember me `ImageView` and a login `Button`.If user clicks(checks) remember me then login credentials should persist else it shouldn't and accordingly it will change `drawable` of `ImageView`.So whenever User opens the app it will show correct image on `ImageView`. This is done using `SharedPreferences`

**xml:**

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/login_form"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/etUserName"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
            android:hint="Username"
            android:padding="10dp" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/etPassword"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:hint="Password"
            android:padding="10dp" />

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_below="@id/etPassword"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/ivRememberMe"
                android:layout_width="35dp"
                android:layout_height="35dp"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:src="@drawable/holo_circle" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tvRememberMe"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:layout_marginLeft="6dp"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/ivRememberMe"
                android:text="Remember Me"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />
        </RelativeLayout>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnSignIn"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
            android:text="Sign in"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white" />
    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

**MainActivity:**

```
  public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {
    private ImageView ivRememberMe;
    private Button btnLogin;
    private EditText etUserName, etPassword;
    private String userName, password;
    private static boolean rememberMe;
    String USERNAME = "username";
    String PASSWORD = "password";
    String REMEMBER_ME = "remember me";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        initValues();
    }

    private void initValues() {
        try {
            btnLogin = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnSignIn);
            btnLogin.setOnClickListener(this);

            etUserName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etUserName);
            etPassword = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etPassword);

            //Persist credentials, if remember me is checked
            SharedPreferences pref = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
            if (pref.contains(USERNAME) && pref.contains(PASSWORD)) {
                etUserName.setText(pref.getString(USERNAME, ""));
                etPassword.setText(pref.getString(PASSWORD, ""));
                if (pref.getBoolean(REMEMBER_ME, true)) {
                    ((ImageView) findViewById(R.id.ivRememberMe)).setImageResource(R.drawable.checkbox_marked_circle);
                }
            }
            ivRememberMe = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.ivRememberMe);
            ivRememberMe.setOnClickListener(this);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        try {
            switch (v.getId()) {
                case R.id.btnSignIn:
                    validateCredentials();
                    onLogin();
                    break;
                case R.id.ivRememberMe:
                    rememberMe = !rememberMe;
                    ((ImageView) findViewById(R.id.ivRememberMe)).setImageResource(rememberMe ? R.drawable.checkbox_marked_circle : R.drawable.holo_circle);
                    checkPersistCredentials(etUserName.getText().toString().trim(), etPassword.getText().toString());
                    break;
                default:
                    break;

            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private void validateCredentials() {
        try {
            userName = etUserName.getText().toString();
            password = etPassword.getText().toString();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }


    public void onLogin() {
        //implement login request
    }


    private void checkPersistCredentials(String userName, String password) {
        rememberMe(userName, password, this);
    }

    public void rememberMe(final String username, String password, Context context) {
        try {

            SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);
            SharedPreferences.Editor edit = sharedPreferences.edit();
            if (rememberMe) {
                if (username.isEmpty() && password.isEmpty()) {

                } else {
                    edit.putString(USERNAME, username);
                    edit.putString(PASSWORD, password);
                    edit.putBoolean(REMEMBER_ME, true);
                    edit.commit();
                }
            } else {
                edit.clear();
                edit.commit();
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
}
```

You can however use this code for reference to implement your specific logic.